# Iin meteor deploy server Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, meteor, fs

in my meteor application I am using node fs to write the file, but when I deployed my application at meteor.com server then I am getting error in meteor logs.

WARNING Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'testaudio/server/uploads/6_40_16_340.pcm'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)

fs = Meteor.npmRequire('node-fs'); in my server and i mentioned the version in packags.json

I am writting file inside /server/uploads/file_name in my application.
I dont know why I am unable to write the file at server. event I tried with full path by using

fullPath = **meteor_bootstrap**.serverDir    that gives path like :-
/appDir/.meteor/local/build/programs/server

Comment: I found this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533669/enoent-error-when-deployed-to-meteor-server