# ENOENT Error when deployed to meteor server

Tags: deployment, meteor, fs

I am using the fs package for my meteor project to open a file on server startup. This works perfectly fine when testing locally, but when I deploy to the meteor server, I'm receiving this error.

```
WARNING Error: ENOENT, open '/server/filename.csv'
WARNING events.js:72
```

The code where the error is coming up:

```
Meteor.startup( function() {
   var input = fs.createReadStream(process.env.PWD + 'server/filename.csv');
});
```

Comment: What is the value of process.env.PWD during startup?

Comment: Directories behave differently between dev and production. If it's a static file, you should just use the [Assets API](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets_getText) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor isn't designed for reading and writing files with `fs`. When you bundle your Meteor app/publish it in production mode the folder structure is nothing like what it is in development.

You can read static files by creating a directory in your project called `private` and placing your text files in it.

You can then read them (on the server side) as @David Weldon suggests:

```
var text = Assets.getText("filename.csv");
```

Keep in mind its not recommended to read files using `fs` incase the production mode directory structure changes between Meteor versions.

Its not recommended to write files in case you have a different server serving the request which may not have the previously written file.